# Mobile advertising - how are invalid or fraud clicks determined?

Tags: mobile, ads

For mobile advertising, how are invalid or fraud clicks determined ?

For web traffic, one of the filters is IP address based, however this does not apply for mobile traffic since mobile devices may share the IPs or may change IPs during a particular session.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can only speculate how they detect fraud/invalid clicks.

The only thing I could think of is the detection of your IP address and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be linked to your `IMEI/UDID/unique ID` code for your phone. It's in the network's best incentive to not mention how their fraud detection works.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the obvious indicators could be,

- You are seeing thousands or millions of clicks / installs from same device ( device identifiers - uuid, ifa etc.) - it's impossible for humans to deliver more than couple dozens clicks a day.
- If the CTR/IR for a campaign is too high (I would think ctr > 45% is fraud, practically its way too lower ( ~ 15%)
- Particularly you are seeing a very high CTR but conversion ( e.g converted installs) is too low - it's also an indicator of fraud clicks.